# Manipulate multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have over 40 data frame in R with the same exact variables. I have manipulated one of them and I would like to do those manipulations to all of them. 
So far I've created a list of the data frames

```
dataframes <- ls(pattern = "file_")
```

(All of the data frames started with file_)

But when I run

```
lapply(dataframes,function(x){
x$bin <- cut(x$Distance, breaks  = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 
                                              1500, 2000, 2500, 6000), labels = NULL, include.lowest = T)
return(x)  
})
```

It returns

```
Error in x$Distance : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Here is a look at one of the data frames.
This is the data contained in one of the data frames.

```
Coast   STCG.2.Commodity    Port.of.Entry       Domestic.Destinations Distance
    1 East/Gulf Alcoholicbeverages Baltimore MD MSA               Albany NY CSA    285.8
    2 East/Gulf Alcoholicbeverages Baltimore MD MSA Atlanta GA-AL CSA (GA Part)    586.0
    3 East/Gulf Alcoholicbeverages Baltimore MD MSA               Austin TX MSA   1344.5
    4 East/Gulf Alcoholicbeverages Baltimore MD MSA               Austin TX MSA   1344.5
    5 East/Gulf Alcoholicbeverages Baltimore MD MSA               Austin TX MSA   1344.5
    6 East/Gulf Alcoholicbeverages Baltimore MD MSA            Baltimore MD MSA      0.0
                                                                        Index         Domestic.Mode Total.Ktons   Ton_Share Total.Ton.Mile Total.M.
    1               East/GulfAlcoholic beveragesBaltimore MD MSAAlbany NY CSA                 Truck      0.0005           1     0.00019568   0.0022
    2 East/GulfAlcoholic beveragesBaltimore MD MSAAtlanta GA-AL CSA (GA Part)                 Truck      0.2639           1     0.17538398   0.1922
    3               East/GulfAlcoholic beveragesBaltimore MD MSAAustin TX MSA                 Truck      1.0548 0.419804187     1.64523022   0.5473
    4               East/GulfAlcoholic beveragesBaltimore MD MSAAustin TX MSA                  Rail      0.9675 0.385059301     1.69025058   0.5020
    5               East/GulfAlcoholic beveragesBaltimore MD MSAAustin TX MSA Multiple modes & mail      0.4903 0.195136512     0.88638634   0.2544
    6            East/GulfAlcoholic beveragesBaltimore MD MSABaltimore MD MSA                 Truck     52.7997 0.999873121     1.24978071 205.7857
      Total.Current.M.                bin
    1           0.0025          (250,300]
    2           0.2128          (500,750]
    3           0.6061 (1.25e+03,1.5e+03]
    4           0.5560 (1.25e+03,1.5e+03]
    5           0.2818 (1.25e+03,1.5e+03]
    6         227.9075             [0,50]
```

Comment: Do you have matrix or data.frames?  Try `x[, 'Distance']`

Comment: I ran `is.data.frame` on them. Yup, they are data frames. I tried running your code and returned 

`Error in x[, "Distance"] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: It was just a guess as you didn't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Uhh, isn't `dataframes` just a character vector? `ls()` isn't returning the data frames within, just the filenames. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Add a couple of your data frames (`dput(head(file_...))`) so we can see what you're working with

Comment: I concur with @r2evans, try `dataframes <- mget(dataframes)` first.

Comment: @tospig `[1] "file_Alcoholicbeverages"   "file_Animalfeed"           "file_Articles-basemetal"   "file_Basemetals"           "file_Basicchemicals"      
 [6] "file_Buildingstone"        "file_Cerealgrains"         "file_Chemicalprods."       "file_Coal"                 "file_Coal-n.e.c."         
[11] "file_Crudepetroleum"       "file_Electronics"          "file_Fertilizers"          "file_Fueloils"             "file_Furniture"        `

Comment: Does the code work on just one of the data frames, outside of the `lapply` statement?

Comment: @tospig Yes it does.

Comment: Due to [type coercion](http://www.r-bloggers.com/type-conversion-and-you-or-and-r/)

Comment: Perhaps try with `cut(as.numeric(x$Distance), breaks ...`

Comment: Bingo. My only problem is this printed in the log (because return (x) and now I need it to add it to the dtataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a data frame by its name use `get()` as in `get("file_x")`.  With multiple data frames use `mget()`.  In your case I think you want:

```
dataframes <- mget(ls(pattern = "file_"))

lapply(dataframes,function(x){
x$bin <- cut(x$Distance, breaks  = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 
                                          1500, 2000, 2500, 6000), labels = NULL, include.lowest = T)
return(x)  
})
```

Comment: `Error in cut.default(x$Distance, breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250,  : 
  'x' must be numeric
Called from: cut.default(x$Distance, breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 
    300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 2000, 2500, 
    6000), labels = NULL, include.lowest = T)`

Comment: @PDog your error suggests your 'Distance' variable isn't numeric.

Comment: `str(dataframes)` suggests this isn't the case.